# How do I show the placeholder in mat-table only to certain cells?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms

I work in mat-table with a formArray and have only one `<input>` in the template. Now I would like to do the following:

Rows should have different placeholders, i.e. if we are in the first row, I only want to show the placeholder test1 in the first cell and in the rest of the cells it should not be visible. In the second row you see test2 in the first cell and nothing in the rest.

It is mainly about how to hide placeholders from cells you do not want to see.

My Code:

```
 <mat-form-field>
    <label>
       <input matInput type="text" [placeholder]="'test' + (i + 1)" [formControlName]="column.attribute" />
     </label>
  </mat-form-field>
```

```
public placeholders = [
    "test1",
    "test2"
];
```

My StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-l9x7ac-8eewte?file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.ts

Comment: Does this stackblitz meet your requirements: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-l9x7ac-e9vmjg?file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.html?

Comment: Exactly. How do I add that the placeholders are constantly repeating and not constantly iterating. That means in row1 there is test1, row2 test2, row3 again test1 and row4 test2 and so on.

Comment: I've updated the stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-l9x7ac-e9vmjg?file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.html

Comment: can you please confirm that the last stackblitz example is exactly what you needed to be done?